# cordova-plugin-ibeacon: not major/minor available when monitoring finds a beacon

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, ibeacon, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'm totally new in Bluetooth & iBeacons world. I'm developing an app using Cordova, I'm using cordova-plugin-ibeacon (https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon).

I start **MONITORING** for **a region with only UUID defined** (no major and no minor defined), because I want to find all the beacons with the same UUID, don't want to apply any "filter" to major/minor.

The callback "didDetermineStateForRegion" is being executed on region enter/exit, but when I dump to console the data being passed to callback... can't found major/minor on it. An example:

```
{"eventType":"didDetermineStateForRegion","region":{"identifier":"beacon_region_0","uuid":"ebefd083-70a2-47c8-9837-e7b5634df524","typeName":"BeaconRegion"},"state":"CLRegionStateInside"}
```

I would like to monitor for a given UUID but also be able to know major/minor values for every iBeacon found for this UUID. Is this possible?

I've also tried with cordova-plugin-ble-central (https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#startstatenotifications), using startScan... but I got the same issue: I scan for a concrete UUID, but in the info of found device's I can't get major/minor values. Example:

```
{"id":"41:4E:B8:F1:F6:15","advertising":{},"rssi":-39}
```

Please help me with this issue. I can't believe that is not possible to get the major/minor values for every beacon found when filtering only by UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the cordova-plugin-ibeacon, **try using ranging APIs**, not monitoring APIs.  This is not a Cordova issue is is a general beacon API issue.   The concept of monitoring just tells you if the identifier pattern you passed is detected or not detected.  **Monitoring does not tell you specific beacon identifiers.  Ranging does.**

Comment: Thanks, great answer, totally OK!

Comment: Glad that helped, @Intelligent-Parking.  Can you please send me a note at the email address linked from my website on my profile page?  I'd like to ask you a question about your use case.